# How to replace MultipartEntity and FileBody in HttpURLConnection (without server side modification)

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, multipartentity

I want to send *.log file to server.
Before, I used apache lib to send *.log file,my code like:

```
FileBody cont = new FileBody(file);
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("log", cont);
reqEntity.addPart("log_name", logname);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

When I used `HttpURLConnection`, the code like:

```
OutputStream outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
byte[] logFile = read(file);
outputStream.write(logFile);
...
```

I knew that, with this modification, server side also must change something to get log file. But, I don't want any server modification.
So, How can I  replace `MultipartEntity` and `FileBody` in `HttpURLConnection` without server side modification?
Thank you.

Comment: Just search this site for some post examples with HttpUrlConnection.  There are hundreds.

Comment: I searched, but in my case, server side had been implemented for get *.log file with old method (use apache lib). so, I want to know how to change client method (from use apache lib to HttpURLConnection) without server side modification.

Comment: You already told that. We know. Now start searching this site for examples. Use the word boundary.

Comment: @greenapps: I found out the solution, thank you so much...